How do you prove that the following sequence diverges?
How do you prove that the following sequence diverges?
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n}$$
for $n=1, 2,...,\infty$.

What have you tried?

@Lorago yes I have tried. But my tries where were quite messy and I felt they were useless information to the reader.

@Morten Check your calculations

@user3612 The sequence is equivalent to $x_n=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n-\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^n$. Since $\frac{3}{4}<1$ and $\frac{6}{5}>1$, $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\to0$ and $\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $x_n\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, the given sequence diverges. I hope it helps!

$$a_n={\left(\frac 12\right)^n-\left(\frac 45\right)^n\over\left(\frac 23\right)^n}=\left(\frac 34\right)^n-\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^n$$
Since $\frac{3}{4}<1$ and $\frac{6}{5}>1$, $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\to0$ and $\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $a_n\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, the given sequence $a_n$ diverges. I hope it helps!
